# How can I combine different values from same column in one column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create this table and use it in my report.

I have a table like this:

| sum | commodity | unit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | a4 paper | x |
| 200 | a5 paper | y |
| 7 | a4 paper | z |
| 410 | pencil | e |
| 300 | a5 paper | w |

How can I create a table like this from the above table?

| sum | commodity | unit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 107 | a4 paper | x-z |
| 500 | a5 paper | y-w |
| 410 | pencil | e |

Comment: Which database/version are you using?

Comment: Add one more a4 paper row to the sample data, and don't forget to adjust the result.

Comment: my database is sql server managment

Comment: I suppose it doesn't matter whether to output 'x-z' or 'z-x'? Or does some rule apply here? And if there were a third entry for 'a4 paper' with unit 'b' the result could be 'x-b-z' for instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If use SQL server means,use below query

```
CREATE TABLE table2(sums INT, commodity VARCHAR(100),unit VARCHAR(2))

INSERT INTO table2(sums , commodity ,unit)
SELECT 100,'a4 paper','x' UNION ALL
SELECT 200,'a5 paper','y' UNION ALL
SELECT 7,'a4 paper','z' UNION ALL
SELECT 410,'pencil','e' UNION ALL
SELECT 300,'a5 paper','w' 

 SELECT SUM(sums) , commodity , STUFF( (SELECT '-' + unit FROM table2 I 
 WHERE I.commodity = O.commodity FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') unit
 FROM table2 O
 GROUP BY commodity
```

Answer (score 0):

As you havn't mentioned your RDBMS, you can use something like this

```
select sum(sum),
commodity,
group_concat(unit SEPARATOR '-') from commo2 t
group by commodity;
```

GROUP_CONCAT works on MYSQL. You can search of alternative of `group_concat` in your RDBMS, like in Oracle you can use `LISTAGG` instead. But the logic is same

Demo in MYSQL

http://rextester.com/ZXZA16316

Comment: my db is sqlserver

Comment: @a.ali,You using SQL server.Is above query is working in your platform.

Comment: @a.ali,But you tagged SQL server and accept result from MySQL query. Wheather you change tag or mark correct answer based on your tag.